# Bulk delete objects in Django using SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite

When I use Django with SQLite 3 and try to delete many objects,
`FilmPage.objects.all().delete()`, I will sometimes run into an error which says

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)

When I tried to limit the number of objects `FilmPage.objects.all()[:999].delete()`, I will get an error:

> AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Django `delete()` is slow because of two reasons:

1. Django has to ensure cascade functionality and foreign key reference when you execute a delete method
2. Django has to handle `signals` related issues like `post_save` and `pre_save`

As you know your models cascading, signal and all foreign key relation, you can use `_raw_delete` API to perform the bulk delete.

Like this:

```
queryset._raw_delete(queryset.db)
```

More details can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Also learn this ticket regarding bulk delete: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9519